# Elasticsearch document doesn't contain _version by default?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

My setup: Elasticsearch 1.4.3 (I know, old, legacy) + python elasticsearch_dsl (or simply http requests).

I'm trying to work with the [versioning support](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-versioning-support) but my documents doesn't contains `_version`. Does the `internal` version enable by default? shouldn't it be returned?

Example to search query (missing `_version`):

```
   "took": 16,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 4,
      "successful": 4,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 32580,
      "max_score": null,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "product_87xxxx",
            "_type": "product",
            "_id": "99104675819",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
               "product_score": 86708.2619362192
            },
            "sort": [
               86708.2619362192
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

**EDIT:**

after adding version to my `scan` query such as:

```
{
    "version": True,
    "_source": {"exclude": ["*"]}
}
```

and trying to perform `bulk` of:

```
{"_op_type": "update",
 "_id": my_id,
 "_version": version,
 "_retry_on_conflict": 5,
 "_type": "product",
 "_index": es_index,
 "doc": {"my_field": new_value}}
```

I'm getting:

```
raised unexpected: RequestError(400, u"ActionRequestValidationException[Validation Failed: 1: can't provide both retry_on_conflict and a specific version;2: can't provide both retry_on_conflict and a specific version; ...
```

But my wish is that if version was updated update the latest version (to avoid deletion of other fields data that was written by different concurrent processes).. trying to keep only `_retry_on_conflict` didn't work.. any idea?

**EDIT2:**
Using `version` without `_retry_on_conflict` throws:

```
VersionConflictEngineException[[products_8768076][3] [product][99104667848]: version conflict, current [3], provided [1]]
```

Comment: You need to add `&version=true` in the URL when retrieving/searching your documents or add `"version": true` in your query: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/search-request-version.html

Comment: please see EDIT section

Comment: That's almost a different question, I'd say, the initial one was about retrieving the version number and the edit is about updating.

Comment: You're right. But can you help with an answer? I'll arrange it later on..

Comment: Yours truly or someone else certainly ;-)